# Why gack Id Error ID: 248606545-14096 (-1147209962) is displayed when I try to review the information for my managed package?

Tags: error, package, namespace, gack, 1gmp

Why gack Id Error ID: 248606545-14096 (-1147209962) is displayed when I try to review the information for my managed package?

I cannot view the details of my 1GMP because of this Gack Id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have opened Salesforce Support case and we have found out the following steps to reproduce the issue

STR (Main case - Gack Id -1147209962)

1. Create an object test with a tab.
2. Create an application contaning the tab.
3. Create a 1GP package and include the application to the package.
4. Truncate the object and undelete it.
5. Add a tab for undeleted truncated object and add the tab to the application which is included in the package.
6. Go to package link and obtain an error.

STR for subcase1

1. Try to add an undeleted truncated object `namespace__Test_Object_trunc__c` to the package.
2. Obtain the error
   Error ID: 797444731-28777 (1934847628)

STR for subcase2

1. Try to add an undeleted truncated object `Test_Object_trunc__c` to the package.
2. Obtain the error
   Error ID: 1837395777-40417 (176622358)

Workaround - remove the tab and the undeleted truncated object from the package or at least from the custom application.

Update from Salesforce support:
All of the Gack Ids are related to the same internal problem

> lib.gack.GackContext: common.exception.AssertionException: ORA-20070:
> Component namespace "NULL" does not match package namespace
> "namespace"

However, the first gack id refers to field `N__c` on `Test_Object_trunc__c` which lacks namespace prefix.
The second gack id refers to layout (when, layout case is interesting, since the Object does have a namespace

Id Name FullName LayoutType

00h4H000002wOiuQAE Test Object_trunc namespace__Test_Object_trunc__c-Test Object_trunc Standard

but it still fails with the same error)

The third gack id refers to an object itself `test_trunc__c`

Also, as far as I know, this is not possible to create an object, a field or page layout without namespace in namespaced packaging org, since when you try to add a new custom object, a new field or a new page layout, namespace prefix is added automatically. This implies, the culprit is in the process of truncation and undeletion. When object is truncated, Salesforce creates a copy of it and its fields and its layouts, so the real problem is that Salesforce removes the namespace prefix during object truncation from the object itself, its fields and its layouts.

---

Update from SF Support as of 31 Aug 2022.

Salesforce Product Team refused to consider this as a bug or known issue due to mention in [SF documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dev_object_trunc_overview.htm&type=5)

> IMPORTANT Truncated custom objects can’t be restored to their original
> state.

while in fact it doesn't explain what is their original state and what consequences it may have.

Suggested to create an idea about webservice or knowledge article about all gack ids. I have created such an idea

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000KU1DSUA1/can-we-get-some-web-service-or-at-least-some-knowledge-article-about-all-gacks

Comment: Thank you for posting the details of the case and the resolution (or at least a workaround), upvoted.

Comment: I am going to persuade Salesforce Support specialist to open Known Issue for that despite he insists known issue is not opened for the issue which is noticed by a single user